# Covid Test Requirement for Dubai Transit From Ireland to Indonesia

Tags: transit, covid-19, ireland, dubai, indonesia

I have a question here.
I have an Emirates flight from Dublin to Jakarta that have 3 hrs and 25 min transit in Dubai. Indonesia have abolish PCR Test Requirement for fully vaccinated people, and according to Emirates website for people transiting in Dubai, you only need to adhere the final destination requirements.

Does that mean I don't need a PCR Test for Dubai transit as well? At what part of Dubai airport do they check for PCR Test (since it is a requirement for travelling to Dubai and if your final destination do require test)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your final destination is not Dubai, **you do not need a PCR test** for transiting.  Emirates:

> Transiting passengers are not required to present a COVID 19‑PCR test certificate unless it is mandated by their final destination.

https://www.emirates.com/sg/english/help/covid-19/dubai-travel-requirements/tourists/